# Regex Redirect Destination

Tags: regex, url-rewriting, redirect

I need to redirect multiple pages based on a single section of the URL, so these pages:

```
site/type1
site/type1/page1
site/type1/page2
site/type1/page3
```

need to redirect to:

```
site/type2
site/type2/page1
site/type2/page2
site/type2/page3
```

In reality there is more than 4 pages involved.

I think i can use the trigger:

```
(.*)/type2(.*)
```

but I'm stumped on how to set the destination so it dynamically populates the rest of the URL with what was there on the previous page.

Any ideas welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your language probably supports replacing with regex.

This is the regex you should use:

```
(.*\/)type1(\/.*|$)
```

This is a bit different from the one you proposed. Your regex will match `type2` instead of `type1`, but you want to redirect from `type1` to `type2`, right? Another thing I changed is group 2. If you don't want things like `site/type1b` to turn into `site/type2b`, then you should write the second group as `\/.*|$`.

For the replacement, you should use `$1type2$2`, which means "the stuff captured in group 1, followed by `type2`, followed by the stuff captured in group 2".

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/1CmJda/1) is an online demo of the above regex and replacement. You can use the "code generator" feature to generate the code that performs this replacement in your language, if you are not sure how to replace with regex.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply look for `site\/type1` and replace it with `site\/type2`

I tested it with vim and it worked fine for me `:%s/site\/type1/site\/type2/g`
Hope it'll help you